# Issue loading data in Hive (group related)

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a sample_data file (created schema earlier in hive table **people**
Upon running following command to load data in table people:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'sample_data.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE people;
```

I get following trace:

> Loading data to table default.people Failed with exception Unable to
>   move source file:/home/hduser1/sample_data.csv to destination
>   hdfs://hive-master:54310/user/hive/warehouse/people/sample_data.csv
>   FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask

Tried following but went In-vain:

```
hadoop fs -chmod g+w /user/hive/warehouse 
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/hduser1/sample_data.csv
```

Further, analysis shows something interesting

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hduser1 hadoop_group      2874 Feb 21 09:50 sample_data.csv
```

Note: File ***sample_data.csv*** has access rights for hduser1 in **hadoop_group** whereas the following line shows that ***/user/hive/warehouse*** has access rights are for the hduser1 in **supergroup**.

```
drwxrwxrwx   - hduser1 supergroup          0 2018-02-21 10:35 /user/hive/warehouse/people
```

How can I overcome this issue? Am I missing any sort of configurations?

Comment: @Bala it's a standard procedure. For that I have to configure a hive-site.xml file and change the hdfs path elsewhere and results would be same...

Answer (score 0):

When you use `LOCAL` option with `LOAD DATA INPATH...` the file is expected to be on the server running Hive. If you don't have access to it, the best way is to move the data to HDFS manually and use `LOAD DATA INPATH...`,

Comment: I have the file on the server running hive and you can see the stated access rights in the question. We have permissions to do so. But let me try that manual copy thing and get back to you upon successful retrieval.Thanks